# Analyse Database Table and Usage

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I just got into a new company and my task is to optimize the Database performance. One possible (and suggested) way would be to use multiple servers instead of one. As there are many possible ways to do that, i need to analyse the DB first. Is there a tool with which i can measure how many Inserts/Updates and Deletes are performed for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Surfer513 that the DMV is going to be much better than CDC. Adding CDC is fairly complex and will add a load to the system. (See my article [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3806001/Performance-Testing-SQL-Server-2008146s-Change-Data-Capture-functionality.htm) for statistics.)

I suggest first setting up a SQL Server [Trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx) to see which commands are long-running.

If your system makes heavy use of stored procedures (which hopefully it does), also check out [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx). That will help you to concentrate on the procedures/tables/views that are being used most-often. Look at execution_count and total_worker_time.

The point is that you want to determine which parts of your system are slow (using Trace) so that you know where to spend your time.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to utilize [Change Data Capture (CDC) or Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519.aspx).  Not sure how in depth you are looking for with this, but there are other simpler ways to get a rough estimate (doesn't look like you want exacts, just ballpark figures..?).

Assuming that there are indexes on your tables, you can query `sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats` to get data on inserts/updates/deletes that affect the indexes.  Again, this is a rough estimate but it'll give you a decent idea.